# NodeJs Store content from all files in directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, file-read

I have the following function:

```
readFiles: function(partidosPath) {
    fs.readdir(partidosPath,function(err,files){
      if (err) throw err;
      files.forEach(function(file){
        if(file) {
          fs.readFile(partidosPath+file, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
            var details = [];
            if (err) {
              return console.log(err);
            }
            commonFunctions.arrayLoader(details, {name: file, content: data});
        console.log(details);
        return details;
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

that reads the content from a list of files in directory.

I need to save an array of objects with each file's names and contents like this:

```
array = [{name: file1Name, content: file1Content},....]
```

I call the function in another file like this:

```
var details = partidos.readFiles(partidosPath);
console.log(details);
```

The problem is that in the `console.log(details)` of the `readFiles` method I can see the information correctly, but when I invoke the method the `console.log` returns undefined.

PD: If I declare the `details[]` of `readFiles` outside of where it's declared the information is not pushed correctly to the array.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are making asynchronous calls.  In asynchronous calls, your program will go on running after the call and not wait for the functions to complete, thus they go ahead and run the

```
console.log(details).
```

You either need to make that a promise and have it wait for the call to finish, or use the synchronous versions of the call which are here. with the link below

```
fs.readdirSync(path[, options]) 

fs.readFileSync(path[, options])
```

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options

Comment: how can I make this a Promise? any ideas?

Comment: Declare the function async and make fs.readdir a returned promise.   After that youll need to use 'await' on fs.readFile.  Then change  return details; to resolve(details);  After that i would use await again on var details = await partidos.readFiles(partidosPath);  I left two links below to help, let me know if this helps

 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise . 
https://medium.com/tkssharma/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-async-await-fa8d8b0bcd7c

Comment: @pedrodotnet did that help?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I changed the approach, I store the matches in a table on a database, I no longer need to read the files from the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You already have 'console.log' statement inside 'partidos.readFiles(partidosPath)'. When the data reading is complete, it will log the data automatically. You don't need another console.log to do that.

Here's the working code:

```
// utils.js

const fs = require('fs')

const readFiles = function (path, callback) {
    let arrayOfFileObjects = [];
    fs.readdir(path, function (err, fileNames) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Read dir error!')
            return;
        }

        if (fileNames.length <= 0) {
            console.log('No files exist in the mentioned directory!')
            return
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
            const fileName = fileNames[i];

            fs.readFile(`${__dirname}\\${fileName}`, 'utf-8', function (err, fileContent) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    console.log('Error occured while attempting to read: ' + fileName)
                    return;
                }
                arrayOfFileObjects.push({
                    name: fileName,
                    content: fileContent
                })
                if (i === fileNames.length - 1) {
                    callback(arrayOfFileObjects);
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
module.exports = {
    readFiles
}
```

```
// test.js

const utils = require('./utils')

utils.readFiles(__dirname, function(fileObjects) {
    console.log(fileObjects)
})
```

Comment: I know that, I just put the console log to check the functionality, the problem is that the data is not saved, the return of the function returns undefined